# Difference Between Control.DoubleBuffered and Control.SetStyle

Tags: c#, winforms

How do `Control.DoubleBuffered` and `Control.SetStyle` with `ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer` differ under the hood and in practice?

Furthermore what is the difference between `ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer` and `ControlStyles.OptimizedBuffer`? The differences defined at the [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx) are not really clear.

Finally, why is it specified by the documentation that both `ControlStles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer` and `ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer` need to be accompanied by `ControlStyles.UserPaint` and `ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint`?

These questions are in regards to Windows Forms Applications (GDI+). I do not know if such methods exist in `WPF` for example but if so.

Comment: Alex why not do a google search on MSDN and see what the difference is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DoubleBuffered property is a convenience property that got added in .NET version 2.  The style flags were getting too hard to figure out by then due to the obsolete DoubleBuffer style flag and the new OptimizedDoubleBuffer style.  Setting the property to true sets all the right style flags so you get the best bang for the buck.  Including AllPaintingInWmPaint, that mysterious one that also needs to be turned on to get OnPaintBackground to be done at the same time as OnPaint, even though they normally run at different times.  Important.

Always favor the property, using the style flags just causes mistakes and hurts readability.

Comment: What makes 'DoubleBuffer' obsolete? I am intersted to know how it differs from `OptimizedDoubeBuffer` still.